# How can I solve this error that I am facing in VS Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, error-handling

[image]

```
gcc : The term 'gcc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:22
+ cd "e:\" ; if ($?) { gcc Test.c -o Test } ; if ($?) { .\Test }
+                      ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gcc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Sounds like your PATH environment variable may not be set properly.

Comment: Have you or the extension installed gcc? If so, find its install location, find the `bin` folder in it and add it to your path. If you don't know how to do this, search for how to add stuff to path in Windows. This doesn't have much to do with VsCode per se. If you don't want to modify the global path variable and just want vscode to know where gcc is, then search for setting compiler path in vscode in <whatever extension you are using>.

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1: install a C compiler and add to PATH

1. Check if you have installed a C compiler;

   - if you have not, download one like [MinGW-w64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) and run the setup (it should add its `bin/` folder by itself);
2. If you already have installed a compiler, but the system cannot find the command `gcc` while you type it from a command line, then copy the full path to its `bin/` folder (example: `C:\mingw64\bin`) and **write the following in the Windows research bar**: `Environment Variables`.
   [image]
3. Open the first result and select "Environment variables":
   [image]
4. Go under "System variables" and find `Path` one:
   [image]
5. Select "Edit" and "New" and write the path you previously copied there:
   [image]
6. Open a command line (CMD) and test if you correctly followed those steps you should be able to run `gcc --version`:
   [image]

The reason to do all this? Path directory is a special variable which contains a set of directories that helps the system to find the executable programs. Therefore, in order to run `gcc` from command line, you need to have its executables (stored inside its `bin/` folder), somewhere in that variable.

#### Solution 2: install Visual Studio (=/= Visual Studio Code)

You might want to know the differences, so well:

- Visual Studio is a complete and "full functional" IDE, meaning you can download it and start programming/debugging without installing external tools (except for additional libraries and DLLs). It's also proprietary software (closed source).
- Visua Studio Code is an editor, so you will need to install a proper C compiler separately. It's open source and you can find its code on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode

Currently Visual Studio has a **free** Community Edition, so I would suggest you to just [download Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), since in my opinion it's much easier to learn C by debugging the code in a IDE and see what's going on inside variables, function call stacks, etc. Then you could learn to compile and link libraries from command-line separately.